# Spotify Web Api Bad Request When Pulling Playlists on Page Load Using Use Effect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite, spotify

Basically when I try to fetch playlist on page load using `useEffect`, I get these errors in the Chrome console:

> GET https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/playlists 400 (Bad Request)
> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Failed to fetch playlists custom error
> at DashboardPage.tsx:44:17

> GET https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/playlists 400 (Bad Request)
> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Failed to fetch playlists custom error
> at DashboardPage.tsx:44:17

```
import { IconPlaylistAdd } from '@tabler/icons-react'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useDisclosure, useInputState } from '@mantine/hooks';
import { Modal, Button, TextInput, Image } from '@mantine/core';

export default function Dashboard() {
  const [playlistName, setPlaylistName] = useInputState('');
  const [playlistDescription, setPlaylistDescription] = useInputState('');
  const [playlists, setPlaylists] = useState([]);
  const userId = 'hidden for privacy'
  const [token, setToken] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
    setToken(`${token}`)
    fetchPlaylists()
    console.log(token)
  }, [])

  const [opened, { open, close }] = useDisclosure(false);

  const renderItem = (playlist: any, index: number) => {
    const imageUrl = playlist.images.length > 0 ? playlist.images[0].url : 'https://placekitten.com/300/300';
    return (
      <div key={index}>
        <Image radius='sm' src={imageUrl} w={150} h={150} />
        <div>{`${playlist.name}`}</div>
      </div>
    );
  };

  const fetchPlaylists = () => {
    fetch('https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/playlists', {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
      }
    })
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.ok) {
          return response.json();
        } else {
          throw new Error('Failed to fetch playlists custom error');
        }
      })
      .then((data) => {
        setPlaylists(data.items)
        console.log(data.items)
      })
  }

  function handleSubmit() {
    fetch(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/${userId}/playlists`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        'name': `${playlistName}`,
        'description': `${playlistDescription}`,
        'public': false
      })
    });
    setTimeout(fetchPlaylists, 500)
    close()
  }

  return (

    <div className="Container">
      <Modal opened={opened} onClose={close} title="Create Playlist">
        <TextInput value={playlistName} placeholder='Playlist name...' onChange={setPlaylistName} />
        <TextInput value={playlistDescription} placeholder='Playlist description...' onChange={setPlaylistDescription} />
        <Button type='submit' onClick={handleSubmit}>Submit</Button>
      </Modal>

      <IconPlaylistAdd onClick={open} size='150' />

      <div>{playlists.map((playlist, index) => renderItem(playlist, index))}</div>

    </div>
  );
}
```

Although, when I open the modal and press submit, it runs the exact same function but it works. The playlists show up.

I've tried setting a timer on the `useEffect` but I still get the same errors.

Comment: please help me :(

Comment: _"Although, when I open the modal and press submit, it runs the exact same function"_ - a request for `/v1/me`, and a request for `v1/users/${userId}`, are hardly the same thing.

Comment: Have you verified, that `token` is actually set, when `fetchPlaylists` executes? If the header you are sending was just `Authorization: Bearer{space}`, and then no actual token value at the end of it, that would probably explain a 400 Bad Request.